# Python: Functions of arrays that return arrays of the same shape

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

Note: I'm using numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

Given 4 arrays of the same (but arbitrary) shape, I am trying to write a function that forms 2x2 matrices from each corresponding element of the arrays, finds the eigenvalues, and returns two arrays of the same shape as the original four, with its elements being eigenvalues (i.e. the resulting arrays would have the same shape as the input, with array1 holding all the first eigenvalues and array2 holding all the second eigenvalues).

I tried doing the following, but unsurprisingly, it gives me an error that says the array is not square.

```
temp = np.linalg.eig([[m1, m2],[m3, m4]])[0]
```

I suppose I can make an empty temp variable in the same shape,

```
temp = np.zeros_like(m1)
```

and go over each element of the original arrays and repeat the process. My problem is that I want this generalised for arrays of any arbitrary shape (need not be one dimensional). I would guess that finding the shape of the arrays and designing loops to go over each element would not be a very good way of doing it. How do I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a 2x2x... array:

```
temp = np.array([[m1, m2], [m3, m4]])
```

Move the first two dimensions to the end for a ...x2x2 array:

```
for _ in range(2):
    temp = np.rollaxis(temp, 0, temp.ndim)
```

Call `np.linalg.eigvals` (which broadcasts) for a ...x2 array of eigenvalues:

```
eigvals = np.linalg.eigvals(temp)
```

And split this into an array of first eigenvalues and an array of second eigenvalues:

```
eigvals1, eigvals2 = eigvals[..., 0], eigvals[..., 1]
```